# Disable Safari autofill for one website

Tags: macos, safari

Is it possible to disable Safari autofill for just one website? I use a website often where this is a hindrance.

It seems like in High Sierra there are "website preferences," but disabling autofill is not included.

Comment: @Stevoisiak Not a duplicate — this question is asking about autofill for form data on the website, that question is asking about autocomplete for URLs in the address bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on Safari from the top menu and then click on Preferences from the drop-down.

Next click on the AutoFill tab and then click on the Edit button beside the Other forms option.

Now from the pop-up, select the website you do not want to autofill data for and then click on the Remove button.